# Is there an android project that provides all views without creating them from scratch?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I'm trying to understand material design components and know-how the views look after modify but I can't see my modify in theme.xml without creating views in layout, So are there any android project on Github provides all views such us `dialog , button , textview , edittext , radiobutton , tablayout , checkbox , slider , switch and so on...` without creating them from scratch.

I'm sorry if my request is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking for an app with all the components included that is Open Source for you to see, perhaps try the very [Material Design GitHub Repository](https://github.com/material-components) and especially their [catalog app](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/catalog-app.md).

Short of that, you can just add the components in a layout and... it would take you less than 5 minutes per component...